# boto3 s3 client documented close() method missing?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, client, boto3

According to https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.close, this method should exist (and I think is described elsewhere as addressing the infamous unclosed SSL socket warning). Is this just another case of AWS documentation flaws?

```
$ pip freeze | grep boto3
boto3==1.24.19

$ python
Python 3.9.10 (main, Jan 15 2022, 11:48:00)
[Clang 13.0.0 (clang-1300.0.29.3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import boto3
>>> c = boto3.client('s3')
>>> c.close()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/sbrown/.virtualenvs/moreroku/lib/python3.9/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 838, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(
AttributeError: 'S3' object has no attribute 'close'
```

Comment: Must be mistake in the docs.

Comment: There are no sessions to "close" -- All connections are REST requests, and once a response is received there is nothing that needs to terminate.

Comment: John, not so: https://github.com/boto/boto3/issues/454

Answer (score 2):

Ahh, looks like release of the code is imminent.

https://github.com/boto/botocore/pull/1810