# Boto3/AWS S3: close the connection (client vs resource)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

For S3.Client, there is a doc at https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.close
for closing the connection

How about for S3 `boto3.resource('s3')`. I have the following code

```
    s3_resource = boto3.resource('s3')
    s3_bucket = s3_resource.Bucket('my-bucket')
```

I know boto3 will close the connection internally. But if I want explicitly to `close the connection`. how should I do it?
I can't find any doc related to `s3 resource` on this.

Comment: No need to close the connection. Boto library handles this already.

Comment: @jellycsc What if I want to explicitly close the connection?

Answer (score 0):

You can now (as of a release a while back, see https://github.com/boto/botocore/pull/1810) call `close()` on a boto3 client. I find this is helpful specifically in many cases to prevent this warning:

```
ResourceWarning: unclosed <ssl.SSLSocket ... >
```

Depending on your use case you may be able to work with a client rather than a resource.

Answer (score -1):

There is no 'connection' to close.

There is nothing in your code that specifically 'opens' a connection.

When an API call is made to AWS, boto3 will:

- Send a REST request to AWS
- Receive the response

This is identical to the way your web browser works -- it sends a request to a website, then receives the response. There is no 'connection' kept open between the two systems.

Thus, there is no need to 'close' a connection because no 'connection' exists.

Comment: John, that's the same thing you said in a comment on my post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72808889/boto3-s3-client-documented-close-method-missing, and as I pointed out at the time it's not correct. You can see here: github.com/boto/boto3/issues/454.